# How to send user profile address to followupboss using rest api in php

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to send leads and inquiry to followupboss crm,
this is the php code i used for connecting to the followupboos rest API
https://github.com/FollowUpBoss/fub-api-examples

everything is working correctly, Now I have to add user addresses json field to the code. but it is not working,

this is my code:

```
"person" => array( 
    "firstName" => "john" ,
    "lastName" => "doe" ,
    "emails" => array(array("value" => "johndoe@gmail.com")),
    "phones" => array(array("value" => "09367099962")),
    "addresses[0].street" => "322 S Broadway"
)
```

on send it is null 
 ["addresses"]=> array(0)

anybody can help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `addresses` into an array of address objects, so it would look like this:

```
"person" => array( 
   "firstName" => "john" ,
   "lastName" => "doe" ,
   "emails" => array(array("value" => "johndoe@gmail.com")),
   "phones" => array(array("value" => "09367099962")),
   "addresses" => array(
        // Address 1
        array(
             "street" => "322 S Broadway"
        )
        // If there are more than 1 address, add here
        ,array(
             "street" => "323 S Broadway" 
        )
    )    
)
```